# Trying to format INT in Money, but getting error: FORMAT is not a recognized built-in function

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to format the amount such as sums like `1588000` look like `$1,588,000`.

I've tried:

```
CASE
    WHEN nb.AmountDollars IS NOT NULL THEN 
            CAST(FORMAT(nb.AmountDollars, '##,##0') AS VARCHAR(50))
    ELSE '' 
END
```

But I'm getting an **error**: `'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Yet I see many answers in stackoverflow people using FORMAT.

Thanks for helping

Comment: This is SQL server 2012 syntax. You must be on an earlier version.

Comment: What version of Sql Server?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty scalar function to split up the value for you.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_FormatDollars]
    (
    @RawValue INT
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FormattedValue VARCHAR(20)

    IF LEN(@RawValue) > 6
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                @FormattedValue = '$' + 
                LEFT(CAST(@RawValue AS VARCHAR),1) + ',' +
                SUBSTRING(CAST(@RawValue AS VARCHAR),2,3) + ',' +
                RIGHT(CAST(@RawValue AS VARCHAR),3)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                @FormattedValue ='$' + 
                SUBSTRING(CAST(@RawValue AS VARCHAR),1,3) + ',' +
                RIGHT(CAST(@RawValue AS VARCHAR),3)
        END 

    RETURN @FormattedValue
END
GO
```

Then use it like this with your field:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_FormatDollars](nb.[AmountDollars])
```

**Example:**

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_FormatDollars](1588000)
```

**Result:**

[image]

I wrote this against a SQL 2005 instance just to play save.